# SOLVED: How to configure Apache2 with Reverse Proxy. Map an internal website to a folder of another (public) website on the same server

Tags: apache, single-page-application, reverse-proxy

I have build a SPA and deployed it to my server. It is running on http://my-server:3000.
I then installed Apache2 and created a static page. This website is on the same server http://my-server:80 and is open to the Internet via a My-domain.

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to add a link on this static page (http://my-server/foo) which is redirected to http://my-server:3000 in such a way that the here deployed SPA can be run from this sub-folder.

I configured a new Virtual host in Apache2 with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName My-domain

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLExtended Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /foo/ http://my-server:3000/

        <Location /foo/>
                ProxyHTMLURLMap / /foo/
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-server:3000/
                SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
        </Location>
        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        LogLevel info

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Although the SPA is accessed and all the files are loaded the application will not start due to the error `No match for URL in routes`. I think it is due to the fact that the SPA is build to run in the root of a website and I'm now trying to run it in a sub-folder.

Does anyone know if this is possible? A solution would be appreciated much :-)

I found a solution which works for me :-)
Since I can use any prefix before `My-domain` like `foo.My-domain`, just found out recently, I changed  the configuration for my Virtual host to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName foo.My-domain

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLExtended Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://my-server:3000/

        <Location />
                ProxyPassReverse http://my-server:3000/
                SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
        </Location>
        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        LogLevel info

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And because my SPA now is allowed to run in the root of a website it is working. :-)

Comment: So what is "the application" in "the application is build to run in the root of a website" actually refer to? Server side or client side?

Comment: It is a client -server application where the client makes API calls to the server to retrieve information

Comment: OK, fine. But that did not answer my question. So you have logic on _both_ sites, the client site _and_ the server site. My question was which of the applications "is build to run in the root of a website"?

Comment: I found a solution that is working for me, see above. The 'application' that "is build to run in the root of a website" is the SPA to which I'm redirecting